Why bounded Laurent Series is not constant?
Suppose $f$ has an isolated singularity at $z_0$, and $f$ is analytic and bounded in an open circular neighborhood around $z_0$ (but not analytic on $z_0$).  By expression of Laurent series, $$f(z)=\sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty}a_j(z-z_0)^j$$ where $$a_j=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C}\frac{f(w)}{(w-z_0)^{j+1}}dw$$ and $C$ is a positively oriented circle lying in the annulus with $z_0$ lying in its interior.
My question is, since $f$ is bounded by $M$, then$$|a_j| \leq \frac{M}{2\pi}|\int_{C}(w-z_0)^{-j-1}dw|$$ However, if $j \neq 0$, $\int_{C}(w-z_0)^{-j-1}dw$ is an integration of an analytic function over a closed loop and thus should be zero. If $j=0$, then the integration equals to $2\pi i$. Thus, the Laurent series is $f(z)=1$. This conclusion is obviously false, but I can't figure out where the flaw is. Any help would be appreciated!

You cannot bound like you did. This is a simpler version of the mistake: since $1,2\leq 2$,
$$
|1-2|\leq |2-2|=0. 
$$
The values of $f(w)$ affect the integral at every point, so you cannot use a common bound. Unless you take the absolute value of the whole integrand, but then you lose the complex integral and the bound is not zero.

I see. You are saying that I cannot pull out the bound of only part of the integrand. Thanks!
